# stringify with rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I'm using socket.io-clientpp, https://github.com/ebshimizu/socket.io-clientpp, which uses rapidjson.

When a event is received, my function is called :

```
void data_published(socketio::socketio_events&, const Value& v) {
```

Value is a rapidjson value. My problem is that the only way I see to stringify it is with Document class.
But to put the Value in a Document, all functions take a non-const reference, for example :

```
GenericValue& AddMember(const Ch* name, GenericValue& value, Allocator& allocator) {
```

I'm used to jsonpp, I'm missing something silly I guess.
The question is simple : how to stringify a const rapidjson Value ?

Answer (score 17):

I am the author of rapidjson. Thank you for your question. I recorded this to issue in http://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/issues/detail?id=45

It is due to that GenericValue::Accept() is non-const.

As GenericValue::Accept() just generates events for handler, it does not need to modify the value and its decedents. So it should change from:

```
template <typename Handler>
GenericValue& Accept(Handler& handler)
```

to

```
template <typename Handler>
const GenericValue& Accept(Handler& handler) const
```

You may patch this to your rapidjson/document.h or download the latest version (trunk or 0.1x branch).

After this change, you can stringfy a const Value as in tutorial:

```
const Value& v = ...;
FileStream f(stdout);
PrettyWriter<FileStream> writer(f);
v.Accept(writer);
```

Or to a string buffer:

```
const Value& v = ...;
StringBuffer buffer;
PrettyWriter<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
v.Accept(writer);
const char* json = buffer.GetString();
```

Comment: I have fixed the second part of the code, you had FileStream as you must have just copied and pasted it. rapidjson is great in my game project. Thank you Milo.

Comment: could you please take a look at my question? [Perform a copy of Document object of rapidjson](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22707814/1967056)